# How to Set the Current day tab on layout loads in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview, android-fragments

I am developing an application, I have used ViewYourPlanWeekly extends `FragmentActivity`.
All the program works fine but the problem is whenever i load this layout Monday tab that is first tab is selected but i want current day tab should be selected. I have used api calls for each tab starts from Monday to Friday. I will post the code, can anyone spot the error and correct me. thanks in advance.

**ViewYourPlanWeekly.java**

```
 public class ViewYourPlanWeekly extends FragmentActivity {

private TabHost mTabHost;
private RouteTrackerApp RTA=new RouteTrackerApp();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_your_plan_weekly);

    if(!RTA.hasSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext()))
        RTA.login(this);

    Intent intent=getIntent();
    TextView username=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.usrname);
    final String sname=intent.getExtras().getString("user_name");
    username.setText("Welcome, "+sname);

        mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();

        TabHost.OnTabChangeListener tabChangeListener = new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                WeeklyFragment weeklyFragment = (WeeklyFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.realtabcontent);
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

                if(weeklyFragment!=null)
                    ft.detach(weeklyFragment);

               if(weeklyFragment == null){
                   weeklyFragment = new WeeklyFragment();
                   weeklyFragment.setTabId(tabId);
                   ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent,weeklyFragment, tabId);
               }else{
                   weeklyFragment.setTabId(tabId);
                   ft.attach(weeklyFragment);
               }
               ft.commit();
            }

        };         
        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(tabChangeListener); 
        this.addTabs(mTabHost);

        //mTabHost.setCurrentTab(3);

    ImageView back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.back);
    back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
    ImageView home = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.home);
    home.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            onHomePressed();
        }
    });
    final Button today = (Button) findViewById(R.id.today);
    today.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            todaylist();
        }});
    final Button weekly = (Button) findViewById(R.id.weekly);
    weekly.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do something
        }});
}
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
 }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    Boolean result = false;
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {  
        case R.id.logout:
            result = RTA.logout(ViewYourPlanWeekly.this);           
            break;
        default:
            result =  super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            break;
    }
    if(result){
        Intent intent = new Intent(ViewYourPlanWeekly.this,Login.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    return result;
}
public void todaylist()
{
    Intent i=getIntent();
    String user_name=i.getExtras().getString("user_name");
    String uid=i.getExtras().getString("uid");
    Intent intent=new Intent(ViewYourPlanWeekly.this,ViewYourPlanList.class);
    intent.putExtra("user_name", user_name);
    intent.putExtra("uid",uid);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
public void addTabs(TabHost tabhost){
    TabSpec tabSpec = null;
    String[] aryWeekTexts = {"Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri"};
    for(int cnt = 1; cnt < 6;cnt++){

        tabSpec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(String.valueOf(cnt));
        tabSpec.setIndicator(aryWeekTexts[cnt-1]);
        tabSpec.setContent(new DefaultTabContent(getBaseContext()));
        tabhost.addTab(tabSpec);

    }

}

/*//with today text
 * public void addTabs(TabHost tabhost){ 
    TabSpec tabSpec = null;
    String[] aryWeekTexts = {"Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri"};
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date date = new Date();
    System.out.println("Todaydate "+Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    int dayVal = Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK-2;

    int dateVal = 0;
    for(int cnt = 1; cnt < 6;cnt++){
        dateVal = cnt-dayVal;
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, dateVal);

        tabSpec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(String.valueOf(cnt));
        if(dateVal == 0){
            tabSpec.setIndicator(String.valueOf("Today "+dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime())));
        }else{
            tabSpec.setIndicator(String.valueOf(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime())));
            calendar.setTime(date);
        }
        tabSpec.setContent(new DummyTabContent(getBaseContext()));
        tabhost.addTab(tabSpec);

    }

}*/

/*
 * Default Tab Context
 */
public class DefaultTabContent implements TabContentFactory{
    private Context mContext;

    public DefaultTabContent(Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View createTabContent(String tag) {
        View v = new View(mContext);
        return v;
    }
}
private void onHomePressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent home = null;
    if(RouteTrackerApp.sharedPreference.getInt(RouteTrackerApp.SHARED_ACCESS_UTYPE, 0) == Constants.VAR_TYPE_SALES_MANAGER)
        home = new Intent(ViewYourPlanWeekly.this,AdminMainPage.class);
    else
        home = new Intent(ViewYourPlanWeekly.this,Mainpage.class);
    home.putExtra(Constants.VAR_WELCOME_USER, getIntent().getExtras().getString(Constants.VAR_WELCOME_USER));
    home.putExtra(Constants.VAR_USER_ID, getIntent().getExtras().getString(Constants.VAR_USER_ID));
    startActivity(home);
    finish();
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // do nothing.
    Intent i=getIntent();
    String userid=i.getExtras().getString("uid");
    Intent backscn;
    if(RouteTrackerApp.sharedPreference.getInt(RouteTrackerApp.SHARED_ACCESS_UTYPE, 0) == Constants.VAR_TYPE_SALES_MANAGER){
        backscn = new Intent(this,AdminSalesPersonList.class);
        backscn.putExtra("uid", String.valueOf(RouteTrackerApp.sharedPreference.getInt(RouteTrackerApp.SHARED_ACCESS_UID, 0)));
    }   
    else{
        backscn = new Intent(this,ViewYourPlanList.class);
        backscn.putExtra("uid", userid);
    }       
    String sname=i.getExtras().getString("user_name");
    backscn.putExtra("user_name", sname);
    startActivity(backscn); 
    finish();
}
 }
```

**WeeklyFragment.java**

```
 public class WeeklyFragment extends ListFragment {

   public String tabId = "0";
   public String accessToken=null;
   public String uid=null;
   String apple_versions[] = null;
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        /** Setting the multiselect choice mode for the listview */
        //getListView().setC

    }
    //list item - start
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    @Override  
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) { 
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
        Date d = new Date();
        String dayOfTheWeek = sdf.format(d);
        System.out.println("Day of the Week is"+dayOfTheWeek);

        System.out.println("TabId="+tabId);

        String[] day=new String[5];
        day[0]="Monday";
        day[1]="Tuesday";
        day[2]="Wednesday";
        day[3]="Thursday";
        day[4]="Friday";

        if(dayOfTheWeek.equals(day[0]))
        {
        int monday=1;
        int tabid=Integer.parseInt(tabId);
        if(tabid==monday)
        {
            System.out.println("Item Clicked "+id);     
            Model item = (Model) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
            Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),ViewYourPlanStoreList.class);
            System.out.println("Output store id=>"+item.getStoreid());
            String sid=item.getStoreid();
            String uid=item.getUid();
            String visitplanid=item.getVisitedid();
            String account_id = item.getAccountid();
            String visit=item.getVisited();
            String storename=item.getStorename();
            String username= RouteTrackerApp.sharedPreference.getString(RouteTrackerApp.SHARED_ACCESS_UNAME, null);
            intent.putExtra("user_name", username);
            intent.putExtra("sid", sid);
            intent.putExtra("stname", storename);
            intent.putExtra("visited", visit);
            intent.putExtra("id",Constants.IDW );
            intent.putExtra("visitplanid", visitplanid);
            intent.putExtra("accountid", account_id);
            intent.putExtra("uid", uid);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You are not allowed to view the store details today", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        }
        if(dayOfTheWeek.equals(day[1]))
        {
        int tuesday=2;
        int tabid=Integer.parseInt(tabId);
        if(tabid==tuesday)
        {
            System.out.println("Item Clicked "+id);     
            Model item = (Model) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
            Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),ViewYourPlanStoreList.class);
            System.out.println("Output store id=>"+item.getStoreid());
            String sid=item.getStoreid();
            String uid=item.getUid();
            String visitplanid=item.getVisitedid();
            String account_id = item.getAccountid();
            String visit=item.getVisited();
            String storename=item.getStorename();
            String username= RouteTrackerApp.sharedPreference.getString(RouteTrackerApp.SHARED_ACCESS_UNAME, null);
            intent.putExtra("user_name", username);
            intent.putExtra("sid", sid);
            intent.putExtra("stname", storename);
            intent.putExtra("visited", visit);
            intent.putExtra("id",Constants.IDW );
            intent.putExtra("visitplanid", visitplanid);
            intent.putExtra("accountid", account_id);
            intent.putExtra("uid", uid);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You are not allowed to view the store details today", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        }
        if(dayOfTheWeek.equals(day[2]))
        {
        int wednesday=3;
        int tabid=Integer.parseInt(tabId);
        if(tabid==wednesday)
        {
            System.out.println("Item Clicked "+id);     
            Model item = (Model) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
            Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),ViewYourPlanStoreList.class);
            System.out.println("Output store id=>"+item.getStoreid());
            String sid=item.getStoreid();
            String uid=item.getUid();
            String visitplanid=item.getVisitedid();
            String account_id = item.getAccountid();
            String visit=item.getVisited();
            String storename=item.getStorename();
            String username= RouteTrackerApp.sharedPreference.getString(RouteTrackerApp.SHARED_ACCESS_UNAME, null);
            intent.putExtra("user_name", username);
            intent.putExtra("sid", sid);
            intent.putExtra("stname", storename);
            intent.putExtra("visited", visit);
            intent.putExtra("id",Constants.IDW );
            intent.putExtra("visitplanid", visitplanid);
            intent.putExtra("accountid", account_id);
            intent.putExtra("uid", uid);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You are not allowed to view the store details today", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        }
        if(dayOfTheWeek.equals(day[3]))
        {
        int thursday=4;
        int tabid=Integer.parseInt(tabId);
        if(tabid==thursday)
        {
            System.out.println("Item Clicked "+id);     
            Model item = (Model) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
            Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),ViewYourPlanStoreList.class);
            System.out.println("Output store id=>"+item.getStoreid());
            String sid=item.getStoreid();
            String uid=item.getUid();
            String visitplanid=item.getVisitedid();
            String account_id = item.getAccountid();
            String visit=item.getVisited();
            String storename=item.getStorename();
            String username= RouteTrackerApp.sharedPreference.getString(RouteTrackerApp.SHARED_ACCESS_UNAME, null);
            intent.putExtra("user_name", username);
            intent.putExtra("sid", sid);
            intent.putExtra("stname", storename);
            intent.putExtra("visited", visit);
            intent.putExtra("id",Constants.IDW );
            intent.putExtra("visitplanid", visitplanid);
            intent.putExtra("accountid", account_id);
            intent.putExtra("uid", uid);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You are not allowed to view the store details today", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        }
        if(dayOfTheWeek.equals(day[4]))
        {
        int friday=5;
        int tabid=Integer.parseInt(tabId);
        if(tabid==friday)
        {
            System.out.println("Item Clicked "+id);     
            Model item = (Model) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
            Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),ViewYourPlanStoreList.class);
            System.out.println("Output store id=>"+item.getStoreid());
            String sid=item.getStoreid();
            String uid=item.getUid();
            String visitplanid=item.getVisitedid();
            String account_id = item.getAccountid();
            String visit=item.getVisited();
            String storename=item.getStorename();
            String username= RouteTrackerApp.sharedPreference.getString(RouteTrackerApp.SHARED_ACCESS_UNAME, null);
            intent.putExtra("user_name", username);
            intent.putExtra("sid", sid);
            intent.putExtra("stname", storename);
            intent.putExtra("visited", visit);
            intent.putExtra("id",Constants.IDW );
            intent.putExtra("visitplanid", visitplanid);
            intent.putExtra("accountid", account_id);
            intent.putExtra("uid", uid);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You are not allowed to view the store details today", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        }
    }
    //list item - ends
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void setTabId(String tabId){
        this.tabId = tabId;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        /** Creating array adapter to set data in listview */


        /** Setting the array adapter to the listview */
       new AdminMainPageTask().execute();
       if(apple_versions !=null && apple_versions.length > 0){
           for(String str : apple_versions){
               System.out.println(str);
           }
       }else{
           System.out.println("null reference");
       }

       //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, apple_versions);
        //setListAdapter(adapter);

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    private class  AdminMainPageTask extends AsyncTask<List<Model>, Void, List<Model>>{
        private ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            dialog.setMessage("Loading Please Wait ...");
            dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Model> result){
            dialog.dismiss();
            System.out.println("Result"+result);
                CustomAdapter mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext());
                mAdapter.setData(result);
                setListAdapter(mAdapter);
            }
        @Override
        protected List<Model> doInBackground(List<Model>... arg0) {
            List<Model> entries = new ArrayList<Model>();               
            try{
                String accessKey = RouteTrackerApp.sharedPreference.getString(RouteTrackerApp.SHARED_ACCESS_KEY, null);
                int userId=RouteTrackerApp.sharedPreference.getInt(RouteTrackerApp.SHARED_ACCESS_UID, 0);
                //String accessKey = "62268bf556";
                //int userId = 11;
                System.out.println("accessKey="+accessKey+"Userid="+userId);
                if(userId > 0 && accessKey != null){
                    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(RouteTrackerApp.NAMESPACE,
                            "RetrieveStoreList");
                    request.addProperty("Token", accessKey);
                    request.addProperty("UserID", userId);
                    System.out.println("tabid in asynctask=>"+ tabId);
                    request.addProperty("CountDay", Integer.parseInt(tabId));
                    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
                            RouteTrackerApp.URL);

                    androidHttpTransport
                    .call(RouteTrackerApp.SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                    SoapObject responseInner = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                    SoapObject response = (SoapObject) responseInner.getProperty("ResponseRetrieveStoreList");
                    int countmain = response.getPropertyCount();
                    String result = response.getProperty("resultStatus").toString();

                    String responseobjsize=response.getProperty("responseObjSize").toString();
                    if(result.equals("true"))
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < countmain; i++) 
                        {                   
                            if(response.getProperty(i) instanceof SoapObject) {                                             
                            SoapObject soapObject =(SoapObject) response.getProperty(i);

                            String id=soapObject.getProperty("id").toString();
                            String name=soapObject.getProperty("name").toString();
                            System.out.println("id="+id+"name"+name);
                            SoapObject account=(SoapObject)soapObject.getProperty("account");
                            //System.out.println("Accountid==>"+account);
                            SoapPrimitive accountprim=(SoapPrimitive)account.getPrimitiveProperty("id");
                            String accountid=accountprim.toString();
                            System.out.println("Accountid==>"+accountid);
                            //address
                            SoapObject address =(SoapObject) soapObject.getProperty("address");
                            System.out.println("Address====>"+address);
                            SoapPrimitive addressprim=(SoapPrimitive)address.getPrimitiveProperty("postalCode");
                            String postalcode=addressprim.toString();
                            SoapPrimitive addressprim1=(SoapPrimitive)address.getPrimitiveProperty("addr");
                            String addr=addressprim1.toString();
                            //visitplan
                            SoapObject visitplan=(SoapObject)soapObject.getProperty("visitPlan");
                            SoapPrimitive visitplan1=(SoapPrimitive)visitplan.getPrimitiveProperty("id");
                            SoapPrimitive visitplan2=(SoapPrimitive)visitplan.getPrimitiveProperty("visited");
                            String visitplanid=visitplan1.toString();
                            String visited=visitplan2.toString();
                            System.out.println("visitplanid"+visitplanid+"visited"+visited);
                            Model model=new Model();
                            model.setStorename(name);
                            model.setStoreid(id);
                            String uid=String.valueOf(userId);
                            model.setUid(uid);
                            model.setAccountid(accountid);
                            model.setVisited(visited);
                            model.setPostal(addr.trim()+", "+postalcode);
                            model.setVisitedid(visitplanid);
                            entries.add(model);
                            System.out.println("Entries="+entries);
                            }
                        }
                    }


                }//checking userID and accessKey ends


            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("ERROR => AdminMainPageTask => doInBackground " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return entries;
        }//do in backgroud ends
    }//async task ends
 }
```

Comment: WeeklyFragment  is supposed to send data to ViewYourPlanWeekly ?

Comment: How to do that ? I am calling WeeklyFragment from onTabChangedListener to begin the transaction !!! what to send from WeeklyFragment and how >? can you tell me Amrola ?

Comment: when you print System.out.println("TabId="+tabId);
is it printed correct ?

Comment: ya for monday it is 1 and so on......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use the :

```
tabHost.setCurrentTab(int tabNumber);
```

you should use the following in your ViewYourPlanWeekly :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
        Date d = new Date();
        String dayOfTheWeek = sdf.format(d);

if ("Wednesday".equals(dayOfTheWeek)) {
                tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
}
```

for all days , just check in if statement then set the current tab .

and give me some feedback

Hope that helps

Comment: Yup got it but i have a doubt in your answer !! TabId goes in this way from 1 to 5 but tabHost.setCurrentTab(n), where n is from 0 to 4 ???? can you explain how this works ?

Comment: i didnt understand what you are trying to tell me ?

Comment: for monday tabId is 1 likewise for friday tabId is 5 but on creating setCurrentTab as per tabId wednesday should take 3 right ? why 2 ? Just now i understood when setting the value for currentTab it takes values from 0 to 4 for monday to friday >